# What does the tilde (~) in macros mean?

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, tilde

Seen on [this site](https://gustedt.wordpress.com/2010/06/08/detect-empty-macro-arguments/), the code shows macro invocations using a tilde in parentheses:

```
HAS_COMMA(_TRIGGER_PARENTHESIS_ __VA_ARGS__ (~))
//                                          ^^^
```

What does it mean / do? I suspect it to just be an empty argument, but I'm not sure. Is it maybe specific to C(99) like the `__VA_ARGS__` is specific to C99 and existent in C++?

Comment: ~ is the bitwise complement, as you probably know. Looks like just a placeholder to me. I don't think it has any special meaning.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

On the introduction page of Boost.Preprocessor, an example is given in **A.4.1.1 Horizontal Repetition**

```
#define TINY_print(z, n, data) data

#define TINY_size(z, n, unused)                                 \
  template <BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(n, class T)>                   \
  struct tiny_size<                                             \
      BOOST_PP_ENUM_PARAMS(n,T)                                 \
      BOOST_PP_COMMA_IF(n)                                      \
      BOOST_PP_ENUM(                                            \
          BOOST_PP_SUB(TINY_MAX_SIZE,n), TINY_print, none)      \
  >                                                             \
    : mpl::int_<n> {};

BOOST_PP_REPEAT(TINY_MAX_SIZE, TINY_size, ~) // Oh! a tilde!

#undef TINY_size
#undef TINY_print
```

An explanation is provided below:

> The code generation process is kicked off by calling `BOOST_PP_REPEAT`, a **higher-order** macro that repeatedly invokes the macro named by its second argument (`TINY_size`). The first argument specifies the number of repeated invocations, and the third one can be any data; it is passed on unchanged to the macro being invoked. *In this case, `TINY_size` doesn't use that data, so the choice to pass `~` was arbitrary.* [5]

(emphasis mine)

And there is the note:

> `[5]` `~` is not an entirely arbitrary choice. Both `@` and `$` might have been good choices, except that they are technically not part of the basic character set that C++ implementations are required to support. An identifier like ignored might be subject to macro expansion, leading to unexpected results.

The tilde, therefore, is simply a place holder because an argument is required, but none is necessary. Since any user-defined identifier wannabe could be expanded, you need to use something else.

It turns out that `~` is pretty much unused (binary negation is not that often called) in comparison to `+` or `-` for example, so there is little chance of confusion. Once you've settled on this, using it consistently gives it a *new* meaning to the tilde; like using `operator<<` and `operator>>` for streaming data has become a C++ idiom.

Comment: My +1, That is a very good find! I couldn't find any standard reference for it & was struggling to understand it thoroughly. Your answer sorts it out nicely.

Comment: How exactly could macro expansion lead to unexpected results, considering that the argument (and therefore, the macro-expanded argument) doesn't appear in the expansion of TINY_size?

Comment: @Random832: Macro expansion has always been a bit blurry to me, but I think for example of `#define unused a, b`, now `TINY_size` would get called with 4 arguments, instead of 3, and thus the code would get rejected.

Answer (score 4):

The `~` does nothing.  Almost any other content inside those parentheses would work the same.

The lynchpin of this trick is to test whether `_TRIGGER_PARENTHESIS_` is next to `(~)` in the expansion of `_TRIGGER_PARENTHESIS_ __VA_ARGS__ (~)`.  Either way, `HAS_COMMA(...)` expands its arguments to either `0` or `1`.

Comment: I'm wondering how this would play out with an argument that's a macro itself.. `_TRIGGER_PARENTHESIS_ MYMACRO (~)`.

Comment: why did he use `(~)` and not `(+)` or something else?

Comment: @Johannes: there is a reasoning provided on Boost.Preprocessor Introduction page, I've cited below. The goal is to use a valid but rare preprocessor token.

Answer (score 3):

The arguments to be tested is placed between the macro and its parenthesis, the macro only triggers if the arguments are empty:

```
_TRIGGER_PARENTHESIS_ __VA_ARGS__ (~)
```

NOTE: Actually the very link you posted states it. I will check for a reference to this in the standard.

Comment: On your note: Yeah, after rereading it a few times after posting the question it came to me... This isn't the first time that I asked a question and some minutes later the solution came to mind... :( Also, your very first sentence somehow doesn't seem to relate to the question directly.

Comment: @Xeo: Sorry, I am afraid I did not understand the context thoroughly  enough to post an elaborated answer, there were loose ends as to why only `~` and I kept ravaging the standard for long with no success. Great, find by @Matthieu M. though, I can sleep peacefully!

Comment: Thanks for your effor anyways. :)